# select event for getting coordinate in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I would like you use select interaction to add a feature, but the **e.coordinate shows undefined**.

```js
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#0288D1',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});
map.addInteraction(select);

select.on('select', function(e) {

  var feat = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate),
    style: style1
  });
  alert(e.coordinate);
  feat.setStyle(style1);

  layerVector.getSource().addFeature(feat);
});
```

If someone know the reason, tell me how to get the coordinate when i click on viewer with this select interaction.

Comment: The main purpose of `ol.interaction.Select` is ***to select*** some feature. Would you like to add a feature on click event?

Comment: Ok, that means if i click on a place which dont have any feature in map, I cannot get the coordinate value with this select interaction, right?   And i have a small question, where i can find all select listener event , like "select"  "handled", on select.on(), even the map.on(), the official web doesnt tell completely all event name. Could u tell me if there is a web to tell all aiavilble listener event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### UPDATE

What you ask in comments (about listeners) can be easier **if** you become a friend of API Docs. In my beginning it was very hard to know them all, but the docs are much, much better so let it be your source.

Each part of OpenLayers has its own listeners, so, for instance, click at [`ol.Map`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html), scroll to the "**Fires:**" section and you'll see the several listeners, the same with [`ol.View`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.View.html) and so forth.

---

To get clicked coordinate inside `ol.interaction.Select` listener use:

```js
select.on('select', function(evt){
    var coord = evt.mapBrowserEvent.coordinate;
    console.info(coord);
    // ...
});
```